# Suppress specific instances of search key in grep

Tags: grep, search

This may have been asked before but I couldn't find it. I am grepping a lot of data files for "NaN" to search for errors; the problem is that if "NaN" appears once in a file, in all likelihood it will appear thousands of times and hence the output will be unmanageable. Specifically, the command

```
grep "NaN" *
```

yields about a gigabyte of output, virtually all of which is redundant.
How do I suppress all the specific lines where "NaN" appears and instead print only the name of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -l "Nan" *
```

Or, if you want to start nixing output, `grep "NaN" * | grep -v ...`

I probably should also mention another possible next step, which is

```
grep -l "NaN" * | xargs grep ...
```

as `grep` needs filenames to work on for a second pass with a new search term.